# calendar to store value in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-ndk

Calendar in the mobile phone (Android).

1. Is it possible to store some values into the Calendar and then view them whenever it is open?
2. Is it possible to start the service at a particular time and stop it at particular time without any user interaction in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Attach Custom menu in your calendar activity. and in that you can use shared preference in it to store in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast receiver in your service whenever you want to call your service.